# Formatting complex JSON response to simple object

Tags: javascript, strapi

I'm trying to format complex response data returned by Strapi to obtain a simple object I can pass to my UI.

The GET request is to the following endpoint:
`http://localhost:1337/api/projects?fields=title&populate=images`

The output JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "attributes": {
                "title": "Github Finder",
                "slug": "github-finder",
                "images": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": 29,
                            "attributes": {
                                "name": "Github-Finder.png",
                                "alternativeText": "Github-Finder.png",
                                "caption": "Github-Finder.png",
                                "width": 1349,
                                "height": 667,
                                "formats": {
                                    "thumbnail": {
                                        "name": "thumbnail_Github-Finder.png",
                                        "hash": "thumbnail_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 245,
                                        "height": 121,
                                        "size": 13.27,
                                        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
                                    },
                                    "large": {
                                        "name": "large_Github-Finder.png",
                                        "hash": "large_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 1000,
                                        "height": 494,
                                        "size": 102.14,
                                        "url": "/uploads/large_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
                                    },
                                    "medium": {
                                        "name": "medium_Github-Finder.png",
                                        "hash": "medium_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 750,
                                        "height": 371,
                                        "size": 67.79,
                                        "url": "/uploads/medium_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
                                    },
                                    "small": {
                                        "name": "small_Github-Finder.png",
                                        "hash": "small_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 500,
                                        "height": 247,
                                        "size": 37.82,
                                        "url": "/uploads/small_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
                                    }
                                },
                                "hash": "Github_Finder_aa83f118aa",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "size": 30.37,
                                "url": "/uploads/Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png",
                                "previewUrl": null,
                                "provider": "local",
                                "provider_metadata": null,
                                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T05:33:46.174Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T05:33:46.174Z"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "attributes": {
                                "name": "github-finder-desktop.png",
                                "alternativeText": "github-finder-desktop.png",
                                "caption": "github-finder-desktop.png",
                                "width": 1365,
                                "height": 777,
                                "formats": {
                                    "thumbnail": {
                                        "name": "thumbnail_github-finder-desktop.png",
                                        "hash": "thumbnail_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 245,
                                        "height": 140,
                                        "size": 14.03,
                                        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269.png"
                                    },
                                    "large": {
                                        "name": "large_github-finder-desktop.png",
                                        "hash": "large_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 1000,
                                        "height": 569,
                                        "size": 110.61,
                                        "url": "/uploads/large_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269.png"
                                    },
                                    "medium": {
                                        "name": "medium_github-finder-desktop.png",
                                        "hash": "medium_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 750,
                                        "height": 427,
                                        "size": 71.56,
                                        "url": "/uploads/medium_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269.png"
                                    },
                                    "small": {
                                        "name": "small_github-finder-desktop.png",
                                        "hash": "small_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 500,
                                        "height": 285,
                                        "size": 40.35,
                                        "url": "/uploads/small_github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269.png"
                                    }
                                },
                                "hash": "github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "size": 40.05,
                                "url": "/uploads/github_finder_desktop_8035dfa269.png",
                                "previewUrl": null,
                                "provider": "local",
                                "provider_metadata": null,
                                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T05:33:46.720Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T05:33:46.720Z"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 31,
                            "attributes": {
                                "name": "github-finder-mobile.png",
                                "alternativeText": "github-finder-mobile.png",
                                "caption": "github-finder-mobile.png",
                                "width": 1079,
                                "height": 1919,
                                "formats": {
                                    "thumbnail": {
                                        "name": "thumbnail_github-finder-mobile.png",
                                        "hash": "thumbnail_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 88,
                                        "height": 156,
                                        "size": 9.97,
                                        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829.png"
                                    },
                                    "large": {
                                        "name": "large_github-finder-mobile.png",
                                        "hash": "large_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 562,
                                        "height": 1000,
                                        "size": 149.01,
                                        "url": "/uploads/large_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829.png"
                                    },
                                    "medium": {
                                        "name": "medium_github-finder-mobile.png",
                                        "hash": "medium_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 422,
                                        "height": 750,
                                        "size": 98.34,
                                        "url": "/uploads/medium_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829.png"
                                    },
                                    "small": {
                                        "name": "small_github-finder-mobile.png",
                                        "hash": "small_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "width": 281,
                                        "height": 500,
                                        "size": 53.63,
                                        "url": "/uploads/small_github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829.png"
                                    }
                                },
                                "hash": "github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "size": 69.72,
                                "url": "/uploads/github_finder_mobile_1c2d812829.png",
                                "previewUrl": null,
                                "provider": "local",
                                "provider_metadata": null,
                                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T05:33:46.911Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T05:33:46.911Z"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

My desired output is as follows :

```
    {
      title: "Github finder",
      slug: "github-finder",
      images: {
           thumbnailUrl:"/uploads/thumbnail_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png",
            largeImgUrl:"/uploads/large_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png",
            mediumImgUrl:"/uploads/medium_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
            smallImgUrl:"/uploads/small_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
      },

      
    }
```

Even the output in this format can be suitable

```
     {
          title: "Github finder",
          slug: "github-finder",
          images: {
               image1:{
               thumbnailUrl:"/uploads/thumbnail_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png",
                largeImgUrl:"/uploads/large_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png",
                mediumImgUrl:"/uploads/medium_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
                smallImgUrl:"/uploads/small_Github_Finder_aa83f118aa.png"
          },
           image2:{
               thumbnailUrl:"...",
                largeImgUrl:"...",
                mediumImgUrl:"..."
                smallImgUrl:"..."
          },
               ...
          }
        }
```

I've tried using various JS higher-order array functions but I have failed.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any question... What exactly is your problem? You can write your own function which transforms object however you want. Like `myObject.title = strapiResponse.data.attributes.title` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response maybe I was not clear what I'm trying to do is o convert the complex object to a simpler one using JS higher-order functions

Comment: there seems to be more than 4 images for `github-finder` in your source data though, so its not entirely clear how you want to ddo the transformation from source to expected output

Comment: Any of the two ways will be suitable, ie. transformation for the first image or for all images in the response. I just need their URLs.

Comment: You should show what you've already tried so far, with a minimal, reproducible code sample. For next time, try to follow [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two maps to get the desired object. Like this:

```js
const result = info.data.map((val) => {
  const images = val.attributes.images.data.map((img) => {
    return {
      largeImgUrl: img.attributes.formats.large.url,
      thumbnailUrl: img.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url,
      mediumImgUrl: img.attributes.formats.medium.url,
      smallImgUrl: img.attributes.formats.small.url
    };
  });
  const res = {
    title: val.attributes.title,
    slug: val.attributes.slug,
    images
  };
  return res;
});
```